# Return row count from mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, comparative-review, mysqli

I want to know if it is okay/safe to use a prepared statement and `mysqli_num_rows` like this:

```
public function getUnreadNumber() {
    $userLoggedIn = $this->user_obj->getUsername();

    // get_result for * and bind for select columns
    // bind_result Doesn't work with SQL query that use *
    $query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE viewed="0" AND user_to = ? ');
    $query->bind_param("s", $userLoggedIn);
    $query->execute();
    $query_result = $query->get_result();

    return mysqli_num_rows($query_result);
}
```

Or should I do this?

```
$query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE viewed="0" AND user_to = ? ');
$query->bind_param("s", $userLoggedIn);
$query->execute();
$query_result = $query->get_result();
$numRows = $query_result->num_rows;

return $numRows;
```

Comment: So is it ok if I use this with a prepared statement ? `return mysqli_num_rows($query_result)`

Comment: http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.mysqli-num-rows.htm

Comment: That hasn't been updated since 06

Comment: What are the possible values returned by `this->user_obj->getUsername()`??

Comment: (If you are not ready to value *feedback and criticism* for [any aspect of the code posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), your question is off-topic.)

Comment: @greybeard what are you responding to?  Was there a comment that is now deleted?

Comment: I didn't delete a comment.

Comment: (@mickmackusa: I was not responding to anything, let alone a comment. My reference to the definition of the topic of the Code Review Stack Exchange has been triggered by the single "laser-like" question `[is it] okay/safe to use a prepared statement and mysqli_num_rows [… or] should I [use get_result()->num_rows]?` From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): `It's OK to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?"`)

Comment: Have you considered using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should definitely not be mixing procedural and object-oriented syntax.

Although it works with un-mixed syntax, the process is working harder than it needs to and delivering more result set data than you intend to use.

I would add `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(*)` to the sql like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM notifications WHERE viewed='0' AND user_to = ?";
$query = $this->con->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("s", $userLoggedIn);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($count);
$query->fetch();
return $count;
```

Assuming the sql is not broken due to syntax errors, this will always return a number.

Answer (score 3):

@mickmackusa is correct, you should **never ever use num_rows** to count the rows in the database, it could kill your database server. This function is rather useless for any other use case too.

Besides, always follow the rule of thumb: make a database to do the job. If you need tell a database to give you the count.

As a code improvement, let me suggest you a [mysqli helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) I wrote to put all the prepare/bind/execute business under the hood

```
public function getUnreadNumber()
{
    $userLoggedIn = $this->user_obj->getUsername();
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM notifications WHERE viewed='0' AND user_to = ?";
    return prepared_query($this->con, $sql, $userLoggedIn)->get_result()->fetch_row()[0];
}
```

Comment: `If you need` *a count* `tell a database to give you the count.`?